# RODBC - sqlSave date

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I use `RODBC` to connect to a Filemaker database and read/write data.

I currently fail at writing a date to my database with this code:

```
sqlQuery(db, "INSERT INTO mytable (a,c) VALUES (98,'01-01-2017')")
```

R then thows an error: `Incompatible types in assignment.`

It works when I reformat column c in the database to `'decimal'` and write two numeric values, so I'm pretty sure the only problem is the format of the date. I tried several arrangements of the data (such as `2017-01-01`, `2017/01/01`, quoting it and so on). My database takes the data format dd-mm-yyyy if I just enter the data manually, so that's not the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: It's a filemaker database; edited the post.

Comment: I don't know this database, so I can't help you.  I would find it strange if the above query would run directly on the database but not from R.  That would imply that the R driver is doing some marshaling of data along the way.

Comment: To clarify: I just enter a date, such as `02-02-2016` into the field in the database manually (not via a sql statement). That works. I did not pass the query directly to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [this FileMaker documentation](https://www.filemaker.com/help/14/fmp/en/html/func_ref1.32.185.html) stating

> ExecuteSQL accepts only the SQL-92 syntax ISO date and time formats with no braces. ExecuteSQL does not accept the ODBC/JDBC format date, time, and timestamp constants in braces.

And - even more important! - this:

> To apply the correct formatting to dates in an SQL query, use the DATE statement. If you do not use the DATE statement, ExecuteSQL treats dates as literal strings

No matter what you are writing, it is taken as a string...

Comment: I don't know Filemaker and since this is not tested, so I can't upvote.  If the OP accepts this, I will be happy to upvote.